# Prevent a winston transport from logging to the console

Tags: elastic-stack, winston

I am currently using this module and can't figure out how to turn off logs to the console.

```
var winston = require('winston');
var logzioWinstonTransport = require('winston-logzio');

var loggerOptions = {
  token: config.LOGZIO_API_KEY
};

winston.add(logzioWinstonTransport, loggerOptions);

winston.log('info', `${responseName}`, response);
```

Then to my console I get something like

`info: List Identity Response error=null, response=[], success=true, id=undefined, firstName=undefined, lastName=undefined`

How can I turn off that logging? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
winston.remove(winston.transports.Console);
```